# ASP.NET MVC Razor Title concatenation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to concatenate UserName in Title with string. Please fix the below code. Like below.

```
@{View.Title = "Delete Confirmation:";} @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to take a wild guess here and go with:

```
@{View.Title = "Delete Confirmation:" + Model.UserName;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
  View.Title = "Delete Confirmation: " + Model.UserName;
}
```